# How can I use a callback function as a parameter, in which has its own independent parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

How can I use a callback function as a parameter, in which has its own independent parameters?

**Example**

```
function func1(a, b){
    console.log(a ,b)  
}

function example(var, callback){
    callback()
}

example(var1, func1(a, b));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
example(var1, func1.bind(null, a, b));
```

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Note that in your case the `this` keyword is not relevant, so `null` is passed for it. Also, as the callback is finally called without arguments, the bound arguments will be the only arguments (they precede nothing else).